# how to compare VBA code in 2 worksheets

Tags: vba, textbox, highlighting

I have 2 problems.

1) I have code which sends out an email with some information. I want that some info are bold. I looked up for other codes, but they seem to have a different structure than mine...

This is the full email and it is made by takings things out of a form + self written text. I want to bold the dates, which are contained in the "TextBox16". How is this done?:

```
enterIf TextBox28 = "" = False Then
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
          "Dear person," & "<br><br>" & _              
          "Latest" & Space(5) & TextBox16 & Space(5) & "<br><br>" & _
```

2) I have 2 worksheets with VBA code. One is the back up of the other. How to check which lines of code are different?

Thank you all!

Comment: If you have two problems, please ask two separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask each question separately.  Nevertheless, for #1, you likely just need to add a bold tags to the html

```
"Latest<b>" & Space(5) & TextBox16 & Space(5) & "</b><br><br>"
```

for #2, copy the code into text files, and use a program that compares two files.  there's a bunch of those out there, like kdiff.